# How to fetch all the literal values from an index field in AWS CloudSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

We are developing an application that needs to populate the tag parameter in the search options with all the literal values from `tags` field in cloudsearch (multi-valued literals).

`tags` field is a faceted index that I would like to fetch its values without defining `q` parameter value in my query.
Is that ever possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query term is always required but you can use the `matchall` operator with the structured parser to match all documents ([docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-text.html)), eg

`?q=matchall&q.parser=structured&facet.tags={}&size=0`

That will give the facets for `tags` across all documents in your index.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is almost the answer I need. Is there a way to not to return the `hits`? We may have thousands of documents and we don't want to return their IDs.

Comment: Actually I'm un-editing that bc I'm not really sure what you're asking. If you're trying to do something facets are meant to be used for, then you probably can't do it. Otherwise please post an example of what you want the response to look like

Comment: Thanks, size was what I needed. The final query looks like the following: `matchall&q.parser=structured&return=_no_fields&facet.tags={}&size=0`